Trying to figure out symboliclink PowerShell error
User is trying to use symbolic link two folders to keep her R scrips consistent. But the error pops out that the resource exists. Is the symbolic link command meant to link two folders together and not create a new folder?
All I have done so far is unhide folders but nothing else really.

Welcome to SO, Kevin Jhang. Please read the information at https://stackoverflow.com/help to learn how SO works. More information is needed for anyone to be able to help. Edit the question to include the line of code that fails, the exact error message, and output from Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\path\to\the\link | Format-List * -Force`. Copy and paste these into the question as text. No pictures.
